# mean value theorem : bounded differential

Tags: real-analysis

Let's consider the mean value theorem in dimension $n$:

$||F(y) - F(z)||_{\mathbb{R}^2} \le \underset{\substack{x\in [y,z]}}{\sup} ||DF||_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)} \ ||y-z||_{\mathbb{R}^2}$

I read that if $F$ is $C^1$ then the norm of the differential is bounded.
I don't know on which theorem this property is based.

I think that it is related to the extreme value theorem since $DF$ is continue on the compact $[y,z]$.
Could you please help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, if $F$ is $C^1$ then $DF(x)$ is continuous; therefore $||DF||$ achieves a maximum on the compact set $[y,z]$.

To prove this in $\mathbb{R}^n$ let $g(x)= ||DF(x)||$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $g$ is continuous, $S=g([y,z])$ is a compact set and therefore closed and bounded. Since it is bounded, the supremum exists (by the least upper bound property of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

The generalized of this property is called Rademacher's Theorem.
It is explained in Chap.3 of this book:
Measure theory and fine properties of functions by Evans and Gariepy.
(This book is now within second edition)